# Word for 'pronunciational etymology'?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there a word of phrase for 'pronunciational etymology', which refers to pronunciation origins and change over time for a particular word?

E.g. *What is the ____ of the word 'one'?*

Comment: I don't think there's one word for this. Certainly the place to look this up would be the online etymology dictionary, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Phonological History](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English) tell you how the components sound of a word evolves but I don't think there's a word describing the history of the pronuciation of a word itself.